# UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal flips Vertically in Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, screen-orientation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am developing an App in Landscape Mode. While doing  UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal flips in Landscape Mode, it flips Vertically.

Is there any way to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
InfoViewController *vc = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Comment: Are you setting this property before presenting view controller? You must set this property before presenting the view controller.

Comment: I am setting property before Presenting. Check out the code.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262908/flip-transition-flips-view-from-top-in-landscape-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[viewController release];
```

check this...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```